# Passing jQuery variable to functions.php Wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm sending the **x** jQuery variable to php file.

This is my jQuery with the ajax:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var x = jQuery('#sbering option:selected').val();
jQuery('#optionvalue').html(x);

  jQuery.ajax({
        url: frontEndAjax.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            'action':'my_ajax_function',
            'id' : x
        },
        success:function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
    });
});
```

This is the function where I'm sending the x variable:

```
function my_ajax_function() {

  if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
    $aux = $_REQUEST['id'];
    echo "ID: " . $aux;
  }
  var_dump($aux);
...
```

instead of printing both $aux and var_dump($aux) on screen 
they're only visible in the console and $aux in php is Null.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpS5a.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KySUW.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried to simply change `$_REQUEST['id']` to `$_GET['id']`?

Comment: @PeterDarmis, yes, with the same result!

Comment: Your code works fine since you get `ID: ...` in your console, in case you want to see output on screen try accessing directly the `ajaxurl` and add to it the proper query parameters since you use `GET`. In your case this would be `?action=my_ajax_func&id=5`

Comment: try to put `var_dump` inside the if and update your question with the result ;)

Comment: another thing: if you are on wordpress try enable debug mode to sede errors

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in

```
$aux = json_decode($_POST['id'])
```

just use `$_POST['id']` only to get the value

and `json_encode(...)` to submit a response

EDIT: also noticed an error in your post

```
jQuery.post(aurl, {id: x}, 'json');
```

Is wrong, because you are missing the complete function or a `done()` promise handling

Solution 1:

```
jQuery.post(aurl, {id: x}, function(response) {
    console.log(response); // just an example
}, 'json');
```

Solution 2:

```
jQuery.post(aurl, {id: x}, null, 'json');
```

Solution 3: Using `$.ajax` (which is equal to `jQuery.ajax`) as specified in another answer

Some useful URLs:

Ajax : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Post : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Get  : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: I've tried both ways, but I'm getting the same Null value.

Comment: post in the question the var_dump($_POST)

Comment: I've tried everything. I've seen that Wordpress treats ajax differently. Could this be my issue?

Comment: as I said,  
post in the question the var_dump($_POST)
and post some code from the server as well

Comment: try to replace `var aurl = '/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/functions.php';` with `var aurl = 'http://www.ved24.no/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/functions.php';`

Comment: you can simulate requests using https://www.hurl.it/ too, this would allow you to set all params

Comment: I finally have got some result, but now I'm getting the echo $aux; only visible in the console and not in php.

Comment: update your question with the new things you discovered and I will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Make an AJAX post to the file like so:

```
$.ajax({    
    url:'address/to/your/file.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {'JSON' : JSON},
    done: function(data) {
        // this is for testing
    }
    }).fail (function() {
        alert('error');
    }).always(function(data) {
        alert(data);                                        
        //Loading or animation until you get a response back (if needed)
    });         
});
```

And Your PHP file should be more like this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['AJAX'])) {  //Checks if there is a POST request
    $data = $_POST['AJAX'];  //Then Assigns the data in the Post request to $data

    .....

} else {
    echo 'Error: No Data recieved';
}

?>
```